# Is there anyway to get all files names without exceptions in C#?

Tags: c#

Update: I be glad to drop the C# requirement, and just see any program that can list all the files running as Admin or System, my question is has anyone seen such a thing?

There are numerous methods of enumerating files in a directory, but all suffer the same problems:

"The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters."

"Access to the path 'C:\Users\All Users\Application Data' is denied"

etc.

Even running under admin, single user machine, it seems impossible to list all the files without encountering exceptions\errors.

Is it really an impossible task just to get list of all the files under windows? Has anyone ever been able to obtain the complete list of all files on their machine using C# or any other method?

[This link from MS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997370.aspx) with the title "Enumerate Directories and Files" , does not show how to Enumerate Directories and Files, it only show a subset of what that will not throw : DirectoryNotFoundException, UnauthorizedAccessException, PathTooLongException,

Update : Here is sample code to run over C and attempt to enumerate all the files and errors. Even when running this as admin there are folders that not only can be access, but I even can't change their ownership to Admin! for example : "C:\Windows\CSC"

just have look at "Errors {0}.csv" log file to see how many places are inaccessible to admin.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;


class Program
{

static System.IO.StreamWriter logfile;
static System.IO.StreamWriter errorfile;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string directory = @"C:\";

    logfile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(string.Format(@"E:\Files {0}.csv", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm")));
    errorfile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(string.Format(@"E:\Errors {0}.csv", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm")));
    TraverseTree(directory, OnGotFileInfo, OnGotException);

    logfile.Close();
    errorfile.Close(); 
}

public static void OnGotFileInfo(System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo)
{
    logfile.WriteLine("{0},{1},", fileInfo.FullName, fileInfo.Length.ToString("N0"));
}

public static void OnGotException(Exception ex, string info)
{
    errorfile.WriteLine("{0},{1}", ex.Message, info);
}

public static void TraverseTree(string root, Action<System.IO.FileInfo> fileAction, Action<Exception, string> errorAction)
{
    // Data structure to hold names of subfolders to be 
    // examined for files.
    Stack<string> dirs = new Stack<string>(20);

    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(root))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
    dirs.Push(root);

    while (dirs.Count > 0)
    {
        string currentDir = dirs.Pop();
        string[] subDirs;
        try
        {
            subDirs = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(currentDir);
        }
        // An UnauthorizedAccessException exception will be thrown if we do not have 
        // discovery permission on a folder or file. It may or may not be acceptable  
        // to ignore the exception and continue enumerating the remaining files and  
        // folders. It is also possible (but unlikely) that a DirectoryNotFound exception  
        // will be raised. This will happen if currentDir has been deleted by 
        // another application or thread after our call to Directory.Exists. The  
        // choice of which exceptions to catch depends entirely on the specific task  
        // you are intending to perform and also on how much you know with certainty  
        // about the systems on which this code will run. 

        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            errorAction(e, currentDir);
            continue;
        }

        string[] files = null;
        try
        {
            files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(currentDir);
        }

        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            errorAction(e, currentDir);
            continue;
        }

        // Perform the required action on each file here. 
        // Modify this block to perform your required task. 
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            try
            {
                // Perform whatever action is required in your scenario.
                System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(file);
                fileAction(fi);
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                // If file was deleted by a separate application 
                //  or thread since the call to TraverseTree() 
                // then just continue.
                errorAction(e ,file);
                continue;
            }
        }

        // Push the subdirectories onto the stack for traversal. 
        // This could also be done before handing the files. 
        foreach (string str in subDirs)
            dirs.Push(str);
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @miniBill: There are legitimate use cases.  Workstation search engines, for example, like Everything.

Comment: Does `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` throw exceptions too? The MSDN only lists a `DirectoryNotFoundException` if your directory path is invalid. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4cyf24ss.aspx. Regardless, it should be simple to write a utility method to catch known failures.

Comment: Can you show your code that is throwing the exception?

Comment: @miniBill : I have a small SSD system drive, I only installed windows on it, but I keep seeing it's usage is going down! I want to see what is eating my hard drive. Trying to get a list of all the files on daily basis and comparing them.

Comment: Ah, for that I can recommend WinDirStat

Comment: @RobertHarvey : Can you show a code that can enumerate all files without throwing exception? For example look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997370.aspx , I have googled this to death, but all I get is that some paths you are not authorised ( on your own machine , single user ), some paths are too long to even know you are authorised or not.

Comment: @miniBill : Windir stat only shows you the current usage, not a way to compare yesterdays usage to todays, on week from now etc. I want to be able to see list of files added on daily, weekly monthly basis.

Comment: Maybe you could use some sort of backup program for this?  Usually they only backup files that have changed, so there may be a way to get this kind of information.

Comment: @unicron : Why is it has to be so hard just to get a list of files?

Comment: Maybe you should write this in C instead of C#?

Comment: @evanmcdonnal : Suppose it is possible to do it in C, then what is stopping us calling it from C#? Why the current implementation of C# is not using a C library that can do that? And it is done by MS, so where MS fails on their operating system with all their resources what chance does a single developer has to do it?

Comment: @Arjang what you consider a failure may actually be the design of their library. Perhaps the C# fileIO classes are checking the length of names/paths prior to calling down to the C functions which just don't care. And the permissions problems you're running into are certainly intentional.

Comment: @Arjang no idea, just trying to provide a solution to your problem.... let's not turn this into a rant against the framework or it will get flagged.

Comment: @unicron : sorry I didn't realise I started ranting, thank you for pointing it out me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is at very least hard to enumerate *all* files without exceptions.

Several set of issues here:

- some path (long ones- PathTooLongException) are not supported by CLR
- security restrictions on folders/files
- junctions/hard links that introduce duplicates (and in theory cycles to case StackOverflow in recursive iteration).
- basic sharing violation restrictions (if you try to read files).

For PathTooLongException: I think you'll need to deal with PInvoke of corresponding Win32 functions. All path related methods in CLR are restricted to 256 characters long.

Security restrictions - you may be able to enumerate everything if you run under system (not sure) or with backup permissions, but any other account is guaranteed to not being able to access all files on system configured by default.
Instead of getting exceptions you can PInvoke native versions and handle error codes instead. You may be able to decrease number of exceptions on going into directories by checking ACL on the directly first.

Comment: Ok, Let's forget about CLR, have you seen a program using C, Assmbly or mchine code that can actually access the entire file system on a single machine ( not network locations ) running under any elevated credential like Admin? Is there anyway to get a complete listing of all the files on ones own machine?

Comment: @Arjang I belive the most files (all?) you'll get with account that given backup privileges. I never did it myself so no precise guidance from me. Search for "SE_BACKUP_NAME", "sebackupprivilege msdn", and read overall securuit articles (i.e. [Running with Special Privileges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717802(v=vs.85).aspx) and [Setting the Backup and Restore Privileges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387705(VS.85).aspx) that come up from above searches).