# visual basic 2010 | continue on error (UnauthorizedAccessException)

Tags: vb.net

Just as the title says, anyone know how to get past this error? This is my first program using visual basic and can't seem to find an answer to this...

Tried

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles GetProfiles_Button.Click
            For Each fileName As String In FileIO.FileSystem.GetDirectories("C:\", FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories)
                CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(fileName)
                On Error Resume Next
            Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

And I tried

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles GetProfiles_Button.Click
        Try
            For Each fileName As String In FileIO.FileSystem.GetDirectories("C:\", FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories)
                CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(fileName)
            Next
        Catch ex As UnauthorizedAccessException
            MsgBox("Unable to access " & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

I think i could make a work around by creating a loop that tests each and every folder but that would be considerably more code and seems quite inefficient... Any suggestions?

Comment: That's obviously NOT VBA ! Please retag your question.

Comment: Sorry but can you explain further what are you trying to do with your code?

Comment: `GetDirectories` returns directory names not file names. What do you you really want?

Comment: indeed, sorry for the sloppy code but I am trying to get it to list all directories and sub directories all the way down, but as soon as it hits a single acess denied it stops the whole script.

Comment: Please dont ever use "On Error Resume Next" in code that someone else will have to work with. Its a holdover from the bad old days (VB6), and one of the reasons VB has had such a bad reputation over the years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get multiple exception on the file methods like `GetFiles` or `GetDirectories`.

Some of the possible exceptions([from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13886420/284240))

- some path (long ones- PathTooLongException) are not supported by CLR
- security restrictions on folders/files
- junctions/hard links that introduce duplicates (and in theory cycles to case StackOverflow in recursive iteration).
- basic sharing violation restrictions (if you try to read files).

You have to iterate all files and folders manually:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim allCFileName = FindAllFiles("C:\")
    For Each fileName As String In allCFileName 
        CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(fileName)
    Next
End Sub

Public Shared Function FindAllFiles(rootDir As String) As String()
    Dim paths = New Queue(Of String)()
    Dim fileNames = New List(Of String)()

    paths.Enqueue(rootDir)

    While paths.Count > 0
        Dim dir = paths.Dequeue()

        Try
            Dim files = Directory.GetFiles(dir)
            For Each file As String In Directory.GetFiles(dir)
                fileNames.Add(file)
            Next

            For Each subDir As String In Directory.GetDirectories(dir)
                paths.Enqueue(subDir)
            Next
        Catch unauthorizedAccessException As UnauthorizedAccessException
            ' log the exception or ignore it
            Console.WriteLine("Directory {0}  could not be accessed!", dir)
        Catch generalException As Exception
            ' log the exception or ...
            Throw
        End Try
    End While

    Return fileNames.ToArray()
End Function
```

Comment: i was thinking something similar but it just seems so inefficient... was thinking there was a easier solution that i just keep overlooking. Answer accepted and up voted, thank you.

Comment: @user1451070: Why should it be less efficient than with `SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories`? The code is just longer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try
    For Each path As String In filePath
        If File.Exists(path) Then
            ' This path is a file
            ProcessFile(path)
        ElseIf Directory.Exists(path) Then
            ' This path is a directory
            ProcessDirectory(path)
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is not a valid file or directory.", path)
        End If
        Next
Catch ex As UnauthorizedAccessException
    MsgBox("Unable to access " & ex.Message)
End Try


Public Shared Sub ProcessDirectory(targetDirectory As String)
    ' Process the list of files found in the directory. 
    Dim fileEntries As String() = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory)
    For Each fileName As String In fileEntries
        ProcessFile(fileName)
    Next

    ' Recurse into subdirectories of this directory. 
    Dim subdirectoryEntries As String() = Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory)
    For Each subdirectory As String In subdirectoryEntries
        ProcessDirectory(subdirectory)
    Next
End Sub


Public Shared Sub ProcessFile(path As String)
    File.Exists(path)
End Sub
```

This will access all the directory, subdirectories and files. Files.Exists should return false if you don't have access to the file, so you should also check on that.