# Async and Await, why two return values

Tags: vb.net, async-await

I'm trying to get my head around `Async and Await`. It's going well but one thing I would like clarification on is why there are two return statements in my method. I'm really looking for an explanation of what is actually happening behind the scenes.

I'll post the full code below as it only amounts to around 80 lines. I'm talking about the central method `AllSubfolderFiles`, which has both `Return counter` and `Return dirsFraction`. What's actually happening with these?

Basically, it is a WinForm application that iterates all the files of subfolders, updating a ProgressBar for each iterated subfolder.

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class frmAsyncProgress

    Private Sub frmAsyncProgress_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        barFileProgress.Minimum = 0
        barFileProgress.Maximum = 100
        btnCancel.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Async Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
        If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtPath.Text) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Provide a location first.", "Location")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Dim sLocation As String = txtPath.Text.Trim()
        If Not Directory.Exists(sLocation) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Directory doesn't exist.", "Location")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Dim progressIndicator = New Progress(Of Integer)(AddressOf UpdateProgress)
        btnStart.Enabled = False
        btnCancel.Enabled = True
        lblPercent.Text = "0%"

        Dim allFiles As Integer = Await AllSubfolderFiles(sLocation, progressIndicator)
        Debug.WriteLine(allFiles.ToString())        'the number of subfolders iterated
        btnStart.Enabled = True
        btnCancel.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Async Function AllSubfolderFiles(location As String, progress As IProgress(Of Integer)) As Task(Of Integer)
        Dim dirsTotal As Integer = Directory.GetDirectories(location).Length
        Dim dirsFraction As Integer = Await Task(Of Integer).Run(Function()
                                                                     Dim counter As Integer = 0
                                                                     For Each subDir As String In Directory.GetDirectories(location)
                                                                         SubfolderFiles(subDir)
                                                                         counter += 1
                                                                         If progress IsNot Nothing Then
                                                                             progress.Report(counter * 100 / dirsTotal)
                                                                         End If
                                                                     Next

                                                                     Return counter
                                                                 End Function)
        Return dirsFraction
    End Function

    Private Sub UpdateProgress(value As Integer)
        barFileProgress.Value = value
        lblPercent.Text = (value / 100).ToString("#0.##%")
    End Sub

    Private Sub SubfolderFiles(location As String)
        'source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16237291/visual-basic-2010-continue-on-error-unauthorizedaccessexception#answer-16237749

        Dim paths = New Queue(Of String)()
        Dim fileNames = New List(Of String)()

        paths.Enqueue(location)

        While paths.Count > 0
            Dim sDir = paths.Dequeue()

            Try
                Dim files = Directory.GetFiles(sDir)
                For Each file As String In Directory.GetFiles(sDir)
                    fileNames.Add(file)
                Next

                For Each subDir As String In Directory.GetDirectories(sDir)
                    paths.Enqueue(subDir)
                Next
            Catch ex As UnauthorizedAccessException
                ' log the exception or ignore it
                Debug.WriteLine("Directory {0}  could not be accessed!", sDir)
            Catch ex As Exception
                ' log the exception or ...
                Throw
            End Try
        End While
        'could return fileNames collection
    End Sub
End Class
```

My assessment is that `counter` is returned and then marshalled back onto the UI thread as `dirsFraction`, but I'm not convinced by my attempted explanation.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `AllSubfolderFiles` function you call `Task.Run` and pass in an anonymous function that returns with `Return counter`. `AllSubfolderFiles` awaits the result of that call and then returns with `Return dirsFraction`.

So, you have 2 returns in the same function because you have an anonymous function inside your original function. You can move that function out to its own named function which will make it clearer that there are 2 different functions here.

Comment: Thank you very much, that makes sense (I was almost there ;) ).